# Issue when typing some characters in OS X El Capitain

Tags: internationalization, macos

In OS X El Capitain when I'm trying type for example ~ (tilda), I'm getting ˜ instead of proper ~, it also highlighted by yellow while typing:

[image]

How do I disable this default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem have the US International PC keyboard layout active.  Go to system preferences/keyboard/input sources and make sure that US is the only one on the list.